# Exception when trying to print all values in a 2D array using a for loop. Need help understanding the Nested for loop too

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I am currently learning beginning to learn Java, using BroCode for Uni, learning how to use For loops to print all values in the 2D array. The code is coming up with an exception in thread: Index 3 is out of bounds for length 3 at Arrays2D.main.

Also I am unsure what the nested for loop is exactly saying, anyone able to walk me through it?

```
{
    //2D Arrays = an array in an array

    String[][] cars = {
            {"Toyota", "Mazda", "Subaru"},
            {"Ferrari", "Mercedes", "Porsche"},
            {"Tesla", "Ford", "Hyundai"}
    };
    //[how many arrays][how many elements in each array]
    
    for(int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j < cars[i].length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(cars[i][j] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Copied code from video, not sure where it went wrong? Pretty much just expecting it to print all values in cars.

Comment: "not sure where it went wrong?" <- Why don't you tell us first how you know that something went wrong. Does the code not compile? Does it produce an error when you try to run it? Does it give you a result you don't expect?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Already mentioned in the description, an exception/error came up: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
 at Arrays2D.main(Arrays2D.java:17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `i++` to `j++` in your inner loop.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < cars[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(cars[i][j] + ", ");
        }
    }
```

The outer loop means traversing the array by row, and the inner by column.
`cars[i][j]`represents the car in row i, column j.

Comment: Ahhh, didn't even realise that! Tysm!